# Why does a procedure run indefinitely in Pyodbc?

Tags: python-3.x, sql-server, pyodbc

In MS SQL I have a procedure. The procedure works fine from Microsoft SQL Management Studio. No problem.
But if I try to execute the procedure through Pyodbc, then it runs indefinitely. On the MS SQL server, the bcp.exe process appears, which runs indefinitely. The bcp.exe process should run for a few seconds - just like when using Microsoft SQL Management Studio. How can I execute a procedure through Python?

MS SQL procedure code:

```
USE [MyDb]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[ReplicaExport]    Script Date: 28.11.2022 9:32:32 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ReplicaExport]
(
       @DestinationReplicaId INT,
       @exportPath NVARCHAR(4000) = null,
       @IsZeroReplica INT = 0
)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
IF NOT EXISTS (
                     SELECT *
                     FROM dbo.Replicas
                     WHERE ReplicaId = @DestinationReplicaId)
       RETURN;

DECLARE @deastinationreplicaidstr NVARCHAR(128) = cast(@DestinationReplicaId as nvarchar(128))
DECLARE @err_msg NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @starttime DATETIME = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
DECLARE @spid SMALLINT = @@SPID
DECLARE @ErrorLevel INT
DECLARE @NewSession TABLE
(
    sessionid BIGINT
);
INSERT INTO dbo.ReplicaSyncSessions(ReplicaId, spid, Start, ERRORTEXT)
OUTPUT Inserted.SessionId INTO @NewSession
VALUES(@DestinationReplicaId, @spid, @starttime, 'Export session started')

DECLARE @ReplicasOwnQuery NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @ReplicasOwnProcessType INT
DECLARE @DataAreaId NVARCHAR(4)
DECLARE @Partition NVARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @AxDBName NVARCHAR(100)
select top 1 @AxDBName = '[' + AxDBName + ']', @Partition = Partition, @DataAreaId = DataAreaId, @ReplicasOwnProcessType = ReplicasOwnProcessType from GM_ReplicaParameters where DataAreaId <> '' and AxDBName <> ''
IF (@ReplicasOwnProcessType is null)
BEGIN
    select @err_msg = N'Export error: Please set AxDBName for current DataAreaId in GM_ReplicaParameters.'
    UPDATE dbo.ReplicaSyncSessions
    SET Status = 3,
    Finish = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    ERRORTEXT = @err_msg
    WHERE SessionId = (select sessionid from @NewSession)
        AND ReplicaId = @DestinationReplicaId
        AND START = @starttime
    RAISERROR (@err_msg, 11, 1) WITH NOWAIT
    RETURN
END
DECLARE @this_dbname NVARCHAR(100) = DB_NAME()
DECLARE @this_db_schema NVARCHAR(100) = '[' + @this_dbname + '].['+ SCHEMA_NAME() + '].'      --current [db name].[schema name].
DECLARE @current_version BIGINT       = CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION();                                                --current version of replica A
DECLARE @min_valid_version BIGINT                                                                                                                                                                                              --min of min versions of changes of sync tables of replica A aware of
DECLARE @SourceReplicaId INT                                                                                                                                                                                                                          --I am replica A
DECLARE @last_sync_version BIGINT                                                                                                                                                                                               --last version of A after import from B
DECLARE @last_known_version BIGINT                                                                                                                                                                                                          --replica A knows about that version of replica B
DECLARE @last_aware_version BIGINT                                                                                                                                                                                                           --replica B aware of version of replica A
DECLARE @filepath NVARCHAR(4000)                                                                                                                                                                                              --save file path (limit for xp_cmdshell)
DECLARE @bcp_format_cmd NVARCHAR(1024)
DECLARE @bcp_queryout_cmd NVARCHAR(1024)
DECLARE @bcp_meta_query NVARCHAR(1024)
DECLARE @security_word NVARCHAR(1024)

DECLARE @divide_by_replicas_own BIT
DECLARE @Schema_Holder INT
DECLARE @tables nvarchar(1024)
DECLARE @tables_query nvarchar(1024)
DECLARE @check_data_exists NVARCHAR(1024)
DECLARE @count int
DECLARE @dbVersion NVARCHAR(40)
DECLARE @instanceName NVARCHAR(128) = cast(serverproperty('InstanceName') AS NVARCHAR(128)), @serverName NVARCHAR(128)
SELECT @serverName = CASE WHEN @instanceName IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ' -S ' + @@SERVERNAME END
SELECT @SourceReplicaId = Id, @security_word = IsNull(Security_Word,''), @Schema_Holder = IsNull(Schema_Holder, 0)
FROM Replica
SELECT @last_sync_version = CASE WHEN @IsZeroReplica = 1 THEN 0 ELSE IsNull(LastSyncVersion,0) END,
                   @last_known_version = CASE WHEN @IsZeroReplica = 1 THEN 0 ELSE IsNull(KnownVersion,0) END,
                   @filepath = IsNull(FilePathSave,''),
                   @last_aware_version = CASE WHEN @IsZeroReplica = 1 THEN 0 ELSE IsNull(AwareVersion,0)  END
FROM dbo.Replicas
WHERE ReplicaId = @DestinationReplicaId
SELECT @filepath = IsNull(@exportPath,@filepath) + '\'
IF (@last_aware_version > 0)
BEGIN
    SELECT @min_valid_version = MIN(ISNULL(CHANGE_TRACKING_MIN_VALID_VERSION(OBJECT_ID(tablename)),0)) FROM dbo.ReplicaSyncTables WHERE syncmode <> 1
    IF (@min_valid_version > @last_aware_version) --change data lost
    BEGIN
        select @err_msg = N'Replica export fail because of change tracking data lost for replica ' + @deastinationreplicaidstr + '. Snapshot export and reinitialization of destination replica required.'
        UPDATE dbo.ReplicaSyncSessions
        SET Status = 3,
        Finish = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        ERRORTEXT = @err_msg
        WHERE SessionId = (select sessionid from @NewSession)
            AND ReplicaId = @DestinationReplicaId
            AND START = @starttime
        RAISERROR (@err_msg, 11, 1) WITH NOWAIT
        RETURN
    END
END
--check if folder is empty
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(1024)
if (@this_dbname like 'DB[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]') select @cmd = 'DIR "'+@filepath+'meta.xml" "'+@filepath+'gmmq.package.end"/B' else select @cmd = 'DIR "'+@filepath+'*" /A-D /B'
DECLARE @output INT
EXEC @output = XP_CMDSHELL @cmd, no_output
IF (@output <> 1)--exists file
BEGIN
       select @err_msg = N'Export error: Export folder is not empty.'
       UPDATE dbo.ReplicaSyncSessions
       SET Status = 3,
       Finish = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
       ERRORTEXT = @err_msg
       WHERE SessionId = (select sessionid from @NewSession)
       AND ReplicaId = @DestinationReplicaId
       AND START = @starttime
       RAISERROR (@err_msg, 11, 1) WITH NOWAIT
       RETURN
END
SELECT @tables = NewId()
SELECT @tables = '##tables_' + replace(@tables, '-', '')
SELECT @tables_query = 'CREATE TABLE ' + @tables + '(tablename nvarchar(100), data int)'
EXEC(@tables_query)
CREATE TABLE #ReplicasOwn(tableName NVARCHAR(100))
INSERT #ReplicasOwn SELECT DISTINCT b.TableName FROM ReplicasOwn a INNER JOIN REPLICASYNCTABLES b ON a.TABLENAME=b.TABLENAME
DECLARE @ord INT
DECLARE @tablename NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @exportmode INT
DECLARE synctables_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT tablename, ord, exportmode
                FROM dbo.ReplicaSyncTables
                WHERE syncmode <> 1
                UNION
                SELECT
                'ReplicaSchemaChanges', -1 as ord, 0
                WHERE @Schema_Holder = 1
                ORDER BY ord
;
OPEN synctables_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM synctables_cursor INTO @tablename, @ord, @exportmode;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @divide_by_replicas_own = count(1) FROM (select top 1 * from #ReplicasOwn where TableName = @tablename) b
    select @count = 1
    if (@ReplicasOwnProcessType = 0) exec ReplicaQuery @tablename, @DestinationReplicaId, @last_aware_version, @divide_by_replicas_own, @exportMode, @count output
    else
    if (@ReplicasOwnProcessType = 1) exec ReplicaQuery @tablename, @DestinationReplicaId, @last_aware_version, @divide_by_replicas_own, @exportMode, @count output, @ReplicasOwnProcessType, @DataAreaId, @Partition, @AxDBName
    if(@count <> 0 or @tablename = 'ReplicaSchemaChanges')
    BEGIN
        if  (@tablename <> 'GM_POSVersionTable')
        begin
            SELECT @bcp_format_cmd = 'bcp "select ' + @this_db_schema + 'GetBcpFormatXml(''' + @tablename + ''',0,0)" queryout ' + @filepath + @tablename + '.fe -T -w ' + @serverName
            EXEC @ErrorLevel = xp_cmdshell @bcp_format_cmd, no_output
            IF @ErrorLevel = 1
            BEGIN
                select @err_msg = N'Export error BCP execution: ' + @bcp_format_cmd
                UPDATE dbo.ReplicaSyncSessions
                SET Status = 3,
                Finish = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                ERRORTEXT = @err_msg
                WHERE SessionId = (select sessionid from @NewSession)
                    AND ReplicaId = @DestinationReplicaId
                    AND START = @starttime
                SELECT @tables_query = 'DROP TABLE ' + @tables
                EXEC(@tables_query)
                RAISERROR(@err_msg,11,1)
                RETURN
            END
            SELECT @bcp_format_cmd = 'bcp "select ' + @this_db_schema + 'GetBcpFormatXml(''' + @tablename + ''',1,0)" queryout ' + @filepath + @tablename + '.fi -T -w ' + @serverName
            EXEC @ErrorLevel = xp_cmdshell @bcp_format_cmd, no_output
            IF @ErrorLevel = 1
            BEGIN
                select @err_msg = N'Export error BCP execution: ' + @bcp_format_cmd
                UPDATE dbo.ReplicaSyncSessions
                SET Status = 3,
                Finish = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                ERRORTEXT = @err_msg
                WHERE SessionId = (select sessionid from @NewSession)
                    AND ReplicaId = @DestinationReplicaId
                    AND START = @starttime
                SELECT @tables_query = 'DROP TABLE ' + @tables
                EXEC(@tables_query)
                RAISERROR(@err_msg,11,1)
                RETURN
            END
        end
        else
        begin
            SELECT @bcp_format_cmd = 'bcp "select ' + @this_db_schema + 'GetBcpFormatXml2(''' + @tablename + ''',0,0)" queryout ' + @filepath + @tablename + '.fe -T -w ' + @serverName
            EXEC @ErrorLevel = xp_cmdshell @bcp_format_cmd, no_output
            IF @ErrorLevel = 1
            BEGIN
                select @err_msg = N'Export error BCP execution: ' + @bcp_format_cmd
                UPDATE dbo.ReplicaSyncSessions
                SET Status = 3,
                Finish = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                ERRORTEXT = @err_msg
                WHERE SessionId = (select sessionid from @NewSession)
                    AND ReplicaId = @DestinationReplicaId
                    AND START = @starttime
                SELECT @tables_query = 'DROP TABLE ' + @tables
                EXEC(@tables_query)
                RAISERROR(@err_msg,11,1)
                RETURN
            END
            SELECT @bcp_format_cmd = 'bcp "select ' + @this_db_schema + 'GetBcpFormatXml2(''' + @tablename + ''',1,0)" queryout ' + @filepath + @tablename + '.fi -T -w ' + @serverName
            EXEC @ErrorLevel = xp_cmdshell @bcp_format_cmd, no_output
            IF @ErrorLevel = 1
            BEGIN
                select @err_msg = N'Export error BCP execution: ' + @bcp_format_cmd
                UPDATE dbo.ReplicaSyncSessions
                SET Status = 3,
                Finish = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                ERRORTEXT = @err_msg
                WHERE SessionId = (select sessionid from @NewSession)
                    AND ReplicaId = @DestinationReplicaId
                    AND START = @starttime
                SELECT @tables_query = 'DROP TABLE ' + @tables
                EXEC(@tables_query)
                RAISERROR(@err_msg,11,1)
                RETURN
            END
        end
        if (@ReplicasOwnProcessType = 0) SELECT @bcp_queryout_cmd =  'bcp "exec ' + @this_db_schema + 'ReplicaQuery ''' + @tablename + ''',' + cast(@DestinationReplicaId as NVARCHAR(128)) + ',' + cast(@last_aware_version as  NVARCHAR(128)) + ',' + cast(@divide_by_replicas_own as NVARCHAR(1)) + ',' + cast(@exportmode as NVARCHAR(128))
        else
        if (@ReplicasOwnProcessType = 1) SELECT @bcp_queryout_cmd = 'bcp "exec ' + @this_db_schema + 'ReplicaQuery ''' + @tablename + ''',' + cast(@DestinationReplicaId as NVARCHAR(128)) + ',' + cast(@last_aware_version as  NVARCHAR(128)) + ',' + cast(@divide_by_replicas_own as NVARCHAR(1)) + ',' + cast(@exportmode as NVARCHAR(128))+ ',0,' + cast(@ReplicasOwnProcessType as NVARCHAR(1)) + ',''' + cast(@DataAreaId as NVARCHAR(4)) + ''',''' + cast(@Partition as NVARCHAR(20)) + ''',''' + cast(@AxDBName as NVARCHAR(100)) + ''''
        SELECT @bcp_queryout_cmd = @bcp_queryout_cmd + '" queryout ' + @filepath + @tablename + '.dat -f ' + @filepath + @tablename + '.fe -T ' + @serverName
        IF (@tablename <> 'ReplicaSchemaChanges')
        BEGIN
            SELECT @bcp_queryout_cmd = @bcp_queryout_cmd + ' && powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "if ((get-childitem """"' + @filepath + @tablename + '.dat"""").Length -eq 0) {exit -3}"'
        END
        EXEC @ErrorLevel = xp_cmdshell @bcp_queryout_cmd, no_output
        IF @ErrorLevel = 1
        BEGIN
            select @err_msg = N'Export error BCP execution: ' + @bcp_queryout_cmd
            UPDATE dbo.ReplicaSyncSessions
            SET Status = 3,
            Finish = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
            ERRORTEXT = @err_msg
            WHERE SessionId = (select sessionid from @NewSession)
                AND ReplicaId = @DestinationReplicaId
                AND START = @starttime
            SELECT @tables_query = 'DROP TABLE ' + @tables
            EXEC(@tables_query)
            RAISERROR(@err_msg,11,1)
            RETURN
        END
        ELSE
        IF @ErrorLevel = -3
        BEGIN
            select @err_msg = N'Export error BCP zero file: ' + @bcp_queryout_cmd
            UPDATE dbo.ReplicaSyncSessions
            SET Status = 3,
            Finish = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
            ERRORTEXT = @err_msg
            WHERE SessionId = (select sessionid from @NewSession)
                AND ReplicaId = @DestinationReplicaId
                AND START = @starttime
            SELECT @tables_query = 'DROP TABLE ' + @tables
            EXEC(@tables_query)
            RAISERROR(@err_msg,11,1)
            RETURN
        END
    END
    SELECT @tables_query = 'INSERT ' + @tables + ' SELECT ''' + @tablename + ''', ' + cast(@count as nvarchar(128))
    EXEC(@tables_query)
    FETCH NEXT FROM synctables_cursor INTO @tablename, @ord, @exportmode;
END
CLOSE synctables_cursor;
DEALLOCATE synctables_cursor;
DROP TABLE #ReplicasOwn
SELECT @tables_query = 'INSERT ' + @tables + ' SELECT TABLENAME, 0 FROM ReplicaSyncTables x WHERE not exists (SELECT 1 FROM ' + @tables + ' y WHERE x.TABLENAME = y.tablename)'
EXEC(@tables_query)
--force check anyway snapshot isolation is off or on->
IF (@last_aware_version > 0)
BEGIN
       SELECT @min_valid_version = MIN(ISNULL(CHANGE_TRACKING_MIN_VALID_VERSION(OBJECT_ID(tablename)),0)) FROM dbo.ReplicaSyncTables WHERE syncmode <> 1
       IF (@min_valid_version > @last_aware_version) --change data lost
       BEGIN
              SELECT @tables_query = 'DROP TABLE ' + @tables
              EXEC(@tables_query)
              UPDATE dbo.ReplicaSyncSessions
              SET Status = 3,
              Finish = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
              ERRORTEXT = @err_msg
              WHERE SessionId = (select sessionid from @NewSession)
              AND ReplicaId = @DestinationReplicaId
              AND START = @starttime
              RAISERROR (@err_msg, 11, 1) WITH NOWAIT
              RETURN
       END
END
--force check anyway snapshot isolation is off or on<--
SELECT TOP 1 @dbVersion = Version FROM GM_VersionHistory ORDER BY id DESC
SELECT @bcp_meta_query = 'select '+
                cast(@SourceReplicaId as NVARCHAR(128)) +' as srcid, '+
                cast(@DestinationReplicaId as NVARCHAR(128)) + ' as dstid, '+
                cast(@last_known_version as NVARCHAR(128)) + ' as know, '+
                cast(@current_version as NVARCHAR(128)) + ' as srcversion, ' +
                'DATABASEPROPERTYEX(''' + @this_dbname + ''', ''Collation'') as collation, ' +
                '''' + @security_word + ''' as securityword, '+
                '''' + @dbVersion + ''' as dbVersion from '+
                @this_db_schema +'replica as replica for xml auto,type'
SELECT @bcp_meta_query = 'select cast((select (' + @bcp_meta_query + ') as knowledge,'+
                     '(select synctable.tablename as name, synctable.syncmode as syncmode, synctable.data as data from (select a.tableName, a.syncMode, b.data from ' +
                     @this_db_schema + 'replicasynctables a join ' + @tables + ' b on a.TableName = b.TableName) as synctable for xml auto,type) as synctables from ' +
                     @this_db_schema + 'Replica as root for xml AUTO) as nvarchar(max))'
SELECT @bcp_queryout_cmd = 'bcp "' + @bcp_meta_query + '" queryout ' + @filepath + 'meta.xml -T -w ' + @serverName
--EXEC xp_cmdshell @bcp_queryout_cmd, no_output
EXEC @ErrorLevel = xp_cmdshell @bcp_queryout_cmd, no_output
IF @ErrorLevel = 1
       BEGIN
              select @err_msg = N'Export error BCP execution: ' + @bcp_queryout_cmd
              UPDATE dbo.ReplicaSyncSessions
              SET Status = 3,
              Finish = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
              ERRORTEXT = @err_msg
              WHERE SessionId = (select sessionid from @NewSession)
              AND ReplicaId = @DestinationReplicaId
              AND START = @starttime
              SELECT @tables_query = 'DROP TABLE ' + @tables
              EXEC(@tables_query)
              RAISERROR(@err_msg,11,1)
              RETURN
       END
       ELSE
SELECT @tables_query = 'DROP TABLE ' + @tables
EXEC(@tables_query)
--SELECT @bcp_queryout_cmd = 'bcp "select getdate()" queryout ' + @filepath + 'gmmq.package.end -T -w ' + @serverName
SELECT @bcp_queryout_cmd = 'echo %date% - %time% > "' + @filepath + 'gmmq.package.end"'
EXEC @ErrorLevel = xp_cmdshell @bcp_queryout_cmd, no_output
IF @ErrorLevel = 1
BEGIN
       select @err_msg = N'Export error: ' + @bcp_queryout_cmd
       UPDATE dbo.ReplicaSyncSessions
       SET Status = 3,
       Finish = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
       ERRORTEXT = @err_msg
       WHERE SessionId = (select sessionid from @NewSession)
              AND ReplicaId = @DestinationReplicaId
       AND START = @starttime
       RAISERROR(@err_msg,11,1)
       RETURN
END
UPDATE dbo.ReplicaSyncSessions
SET Status = 0,
Finish = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
ERRORTEXT = 'Export completed successfully.'
WHERE SessionId = (select sessionid from @NewSession)
AND ReplicaId = @DestinationReplicaId
AND START = @starttime
END
```

I tried to execute the procedure through Pyodbc, but it runs indefinitely with an infinite bcp.exe process on SQL Server.

Python code:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};SERVER="MyServer";DATABASE='MyDB';UID='sa';PWD='MyPWD';TrustServerCertificate=Yes')
cnxn.execute("exec replicaexport 0")
cnxn.commit()
```

Comment: I'm honestly surprised that this would work from SSMS at all. `bcp.exe` opens its own connection back into the database, so will be operating on a different `sp_id`, and will almost certainly be blocked on (at least) one of the tables that the stored procedure itself is modifying. So which bcp.exe command invocation is it? Have you checked the commandline arguments on the Details tab of Task Manager or some other process enumerator?

Comment: The SQL application is used as is, I am not the author of the SQL application and I am not allowed to change the SQL code. This procedure works from SSMS, also it works from SQL cmd - I tested it myself. I need to run this procedure from Python. It's impossible?

Comment: Using SQLCMD from Python solves my problem:

os.system('sqlcmd.exe -S server -Usa -Pmypass -dMy_DB -Q"exec replicaexport 0"')